# Converting String ID field in report

Tags: apex, reporting

I have an ID string field in a custom object. This ID could be a lead, case or opportunity. I am generating reports on the custom object with a column for this field. Is it possible to convert this ID into a lead/case/opp name in the report dynamically.

Comment: what kind of report you are generating, are you talking about salesforce standard Report or you try to implement custom VF Report.

Comment: I'm trying to generate a salesforce standard report. It is a tabular report just printing the fields of the custom object one of which is an ID field stored in a string format. I want to convert the ID to a object to print the name.

Comment: Are you wanting to use the Id to perform a lookup or do you just want to know the object it came from? If the latter, you can easily create a formula using the prefix of the id where an `Account` starts with `001`, `Contact : 005`, `Opp :  006`, `Lead : 00Q`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to do a lookup to get an object field value. Can this be done using reports or do you suggest creating a visualforce page to represent data in a tabular format?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I doubt you can do that with Report itself although reports allowed some sort of formula options but that won't help you, in your case I believe you want to display it in your tabular report as column.

I suggest please create a text type formula field on your custom object and then write the formula which can take the first three letters from that `ID` field and identify the object name, see below formula for your reference:

```
IF(IdField__c != null && IdField__c != '', 
IF(MID(IdField__c, 0, 3) == '006','Opportunity', 
IF(MID(IdField__c, 0, 3) == '00Q','Lead', 
IF(MID(IdField__c, 0, 3) == '500','Case',''))), '')
```

Please check first three letters of the id and respectively change the object name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to do a lookup using the ID to get some field values. Not sure if report is the right way to do it or if I should be creating a visualforce page in tabular format

Comment: To get the lookup based field value, you need a lookup, but in your case you have string(text) field which is also referenced with multiple objects records. in that case I would suggest go ahead with VF page or use trigger to populate the lookup based values in a separate field, and then use that field in reports

Comment: Thanks! A trigger to populate the lookup field sounds like a decent solution.